# How to organize range search in sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have two range fields in a form.
Min and max fields.

```
= form_tag search_items_path, :method => :get do
  %label
    = t('form.price')
  = text_field_tag :min_price, params[:min_price]
  = text_field_tag :max_price, params[:max_price]

  = submit_tag t('form.search')


= render "search_result"
```

How to organize range search in sphinx?

Comment: can you explain your requirements more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

```
define_index do
  indexes name

  has mileage
end
Car.search :with => {:mileage => 100..150000}
```